# Is it possible to add conditional properties to CSS using foundation 4 or bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

An example of what I mean:

I have an image inside a div that I want to be left-aligned when the viewport is large (and it is side by side with another image that is inside another div, each one taking 6 columns) and to be centered when it is small (as it is going to occupy all columns). I would like to know if it is possible and how, using foundation or bootstrap. Do we need to use media-queries?

Sorry, but I didn't understand yet if that's something you use with CSS or if you need to use LESS.

Thank you, I hope you can help me understanding how this works in frameworks.

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3 or 2.3.2? They have different set-ups for their media queries.  Also when you mean small do you mean phone or tablet small?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say using media queries is your best bet, for your specific example it would be as follows

```
@media (max-width:[SMALL SIZE]) {
   .divClass img{
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
   }
}


@media (max-width:[LARGE SIZE]) {
   .divClass img{
       float: left;
   }
}
```